# Exception not being caught in a string of queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello I have a php registration script that creates a database user then creates a database for then user and then creates the tables for that database, in the appropriate order.

a series of queries are contained in 1 string. 
Here is the list of queries executed: http://pastebin.com/REBMFyyT
As you may see I have on purpose miss-typed the "create table clients" query to check my custom error logging. The issue is that the exception is not being caught. here is the function responsible:

```
public function register() {

    global $session;
    global $cookie;

    $credentials = array('username' => $this->getPostUsername(), 'password' => $this->getPostPassword());

    if (!$this->areValid($credentials)) {
        echo 'Invalid credentials!';
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->userExists($credentials['username'])) {
        echo 'User already exists!';
        return false;
    }

    try{

        $this->rootConnection->beginTransaction();

        // create user record
        $statement1 = $this->rootConnection->prepare($this->createUserRecord());
        $username = $credentials['username'];
        $password = MD5($credentials['password'] . $this->salt);
        $statement1->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $statement1->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $statement1->execute();

        $user_id = $this->rootConnection->lastInsertId();
        $user_database = "user_$user_id";
        $db_username = "user_$user_id";
        $db_password = MD5($db_username . $this->salt);

        // update user database info
        $statement2 = $this->rootConnection->prepare($this->updateUserDbInfo());
        $statement2->bindParam(':database', $user_database);
        $statement2->bindParam(':db_username', $db_username);
        $statement2->bindParam(':db_password', $db_password);
        $statement2->bindParam(':id', $user_id);
        $statement2->execute();

        $this->rootConnection->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->log($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }


    $userData = $this->getUserById($user_id);

    $session->set($userData);
    $cookie->set('username', $username);
    $cookie->set('password', $password);

    $megaQuery = $this->createDatabaseUser() . ";\n" .
                 $this->grantUserUsage() . ";\n" .
                 $this->createUserDatabase($user_database) . ";\n" .
                 $this->grantUserDatabasePrivileges() . ";\n" .
                 $this->createDriversTable($user_database) . ";\n" .
                 $this->createClientsTable($user_database) . ";\n" .
                 $this->createCarsTable($user_database) . ";\n" .
                 $this->createRecordsTable($user_database);

    try{

        $statement3 = $this->rootConnection->prepare($megaQuery);
        $statement3->bindParam(':db_username', $db_username);
        $statement3->bindParam(':db_password', $db_password);
        $statement3->execute();

        return true;

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->log($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return false;       

}
```

Furthermore, this is how I initialize my database connection:

```
private function connect(){
    $this->rootConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->rootHost;dbname=$this->rootDatabase", $this->rootUsername, $this->rootPassword, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")) or die("Manager error connecting to database!");
    $this->rootConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->rootConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
}
```

My question is obvious why isn't the exception being caught and furthermore logged?
PS: The variable megaQuery contains & merges the queries for privileges, database & user creation on MySql which are not 'transactionable' queries. Also filesystem privileges are not an issue in this case. Finally the logging function:

```
public function log($data, $file = 'log/errors.log') {

    $now = $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data = "[$now]\t$data\n";

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        echo 'file exists<br>';
        file_put_contents($file,  $data, FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        echo 'file will be created<br>';
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do the queries run successfully when provided valid SQL?

Comment: yes they work just fine. My Issue is to catch an exception if a query is not valid - malformed and mySQL returns and error. In this case I misstyped 'create tables' to 'create tabdles' but no exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

without reading the question body (which smells as too localized anyway), just a check-list

To catch an exception:

1. Exception have to be thrown. In case of PDO it have to be [configured to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

   - of course, there should be a cause for the exception
2. If namespaces are in use, a root path have to be used, e.g. `\PDOException`
3. No typos in the code.

Comment: In this case if I have misstyped query shouldn't be caught ?

Comment: Hey, [weren't it you who told me that already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424100/transaction-pdo-exception-not-caught-and-no-rollback?noredirect=1#comment28797811_19424100)

Comment: Yea but this is slightly a different issue I set  $this->rootConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); and I'm trying to execute all queries in one statement but in case if some query is misstyped I dont get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Because you didnt throw exception if something goes wrong.

You should do for example :

```
if(is_null($db_password))
 throw new Exception('Your error message here');
```

Comment: PDO is intelligent enough to throw an exception by itself